# Add range info into the boundingboxes

Tags: python, object-detection, ros, yolo, lidar

I'm new at Ros. I want to add distance information to the bounding boxes I bought with Yolov7 using 2D lidar. I will do these on Ros Noetic. Can you guide me for this?
And if so, can you recommend a sample project?

I prepared something like this for this, but while the maximum range of my lidar is 12 m, the outputs reach approximately 40 m:

```
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point, Pose2D
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker, MarkerArray
from camera_2d_lidar_calibration.msg import RangeDetection
from vision_msgs.msg import Detection2D, Detection2DArray, BoundingBox2D, BoundingBox2DArray
from sensor_msgs.msg import Range, LaserScan
import math



class ObjectDetection:
    def __init__(self):
        
        rospy.init_node('fusion_object_and_angle_detection')

        # Initialize variables
        self.object_detected = False
        self.indeks = None
        self.object_centers = []         
        self.distance_measurements = [] 
        self.object_points = []
        self.fov = 60
        self.width = 640
        self.center_x = 0
        self.center_y = 0  
        self.distance_appr = 0
        self.x1 = 0
        self.x2 = 0 

        rospy.Subscriber("/yolov7/yolov7", Detection2DArray, self.object_detection_callback)
        rospy.Subscriber("/scan", LaserScan, self.calculate_distance_callback)
        rospy.Subscriber("/yolov7/yolov7", Detection2DArray, self.calculate_bbox_callback)

    # Callback function for object detection
    def object_detection_callback(self, msg):
        self.object_detected = True  # Assume object detected when callback is triggered
        
    def calculate_bbox_callback(self, msg):
          for detection in msg.detections:
            bbox = detection.bbox  # Bounding box of the current detection
            size_x = bbox.size_x
            size_y = bbox.size_y
            center_x = bbox.center.x
            center_y = bbox.center.y
            
            x2 = center_x + (size_x / 2)
            x1 = center_x - (size_x / 2)
            
            self.x1 = x1
            self.x2 = x2

            # Call the calculate_distance_callback function for each bounding box
            self.calculate_distance_callback(msg)

    # Function that calculates the data range by combining center coordinate and distance data        
    def calculate_distance_callback(self, msg):
        angle_max = (self.fov / self.width) * self.x2
        angle_x2_detection = 60.0 + angle_max
        self.indeks_x2 = int(angle_x2_detection)
        if 0 <= self.indeks_x2 < len(msg.ranges):
                self.distance_x2 = msg.ranges[self.indeks_x2]
        else:
                print("Index outside array bounds.")

        angle_x1 = (self.fov / self.width) * self.x1
        angle_x1_detection = 60.0 + angle_x1
        self.indeks_x1 = int(angle_x1_detection)
        if 0 <= self.indeks_x1 < len(msg.ranges):
                self.distance_x1 = msg.ranges[self.indeks_x1]
        else:
               print("Index outside array bounds.")

        distance_appr = (self.distance_x2 + self.indeks_x1) / 2
        print("Distance approximately: ", distance_appr)
        
    
    def run(self):
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            if self.object_detected:
                self.object_centers.append((self.center_x, self.center_y))
                self.distance_measurements.append(self.distance_appr)

                center_point = Point()

                center_point.x = self.center_x
                center_point.y = self.center_y
                center_point.z = self.distance_appr

                self.object_points.append(center_point)

                range_detection = RangeDetection()
                range_detection.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
                range_detection.header.frame_id = "base_link"
                range_detection.radiation_type = 0
                range_detection.field_of_view = 60
                range_detection.center_x = center_point.x
                range_detection.center_y = center_point.y
                range_detection.distance_appr = center_point.z

                self.pub_range_detection.publish(range_detection)
                self.pub_range.publish(self.distance_appr)

                self.object_detected = False

            rospy.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fusion = ObjectDetection()
    fusion.run()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.